# Example on a product topology

Tags: general-topology

There is a proposition that states: The product topology is the weakest topology on $X$ that makes each projection $P_i (i \in I)$ continuous.

So I was searching for an example of a product topology where the projections of $X$ aren't continuous, but I didn't find any yet. Can anyone in finding an example please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I was searching for an example of a product topology

I assume you've meant "an example of a topology on product". There is no "other" product topology, there is only one.

Anyway take the trivial topology on $X\times Y$ (meaning only $\emptyset$ and $X\times Y$ are open) and assume that $X$ has a proper, nonempty open subset $U$ (i.e. the topology on $X$ is not trivial). Let $\pi:X\times Y\to X$ be the projection. Is $\pi^{-1}(U)$ open?

Comment: Thank you @freakish, but can you please explain more to me what do you mean by a topology on product? Is it not called a product topology? I just didn't understand what you mean by thi part.

Comment: @FareedAF product is $X\times Y$. A topology on product is a topology on $X\times Y$. [The product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) is a very specific topology on a product: the one generated by products of open subsets. So there is only one product topology. But there are many topologies on product. It's a linguistic nuance.